# selectOneRadio lost checked value inside a dataList with pagination

Tags: jsf, primefaces, pagination, datalist, selectoneradio

I have this example code,

My xhtml page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:dataList value="#{dataListView.lista}" var="l" type="unordered"
        itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="1" styleClass="paginated">
        <f:facet name="header">
                Paginator
            </f:facet>
        <p:selectOneRadio id="resposta" value="#{dataListView.resposta}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certo" itemValue="Certo" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Errado" itemValue="Errado" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:dataList>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My Bean

```
package br.com.so.teste;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.so.modelo.Questao;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DataListView implements Serializable {

    private List<String> lista;
    private String resposta;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("1");
        lista.add("2");
        lista.add("3");
        lista.add("4");
        lista.add("5");
    }

    public List<String> getLista() {
        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<String> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public String getResposta() {
        return resposta;
    }

    public void setResposta(String resposta) {
        this.resposta = resposta;
    }

}
```

The error appear when i change the page view, in pagination have (1,2,3...) if i check the radio button in page '1' and i go to page '2' and i come back to page '1' the radio button is not checked.
Why does it happen?
How do i fix it?
I need to keep the value checked in the radioButtons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using this.

I create 2 SelectoneRadio, one geting the checked value, if exists..
And another only puting the value.
I use Ajax to pass the ID.
If the map contains the id, i use ajax only to update, because the radio set the value directly in the map.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formulario">
        <p:dataList value="#{dataListView.lista}" var="l" type="unordered"
            itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="1" styleClass="paginated">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Paginator
            </f:facet>
            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{dataListView.teste}"
                rendered="#{dataListView.resposta[l] == null}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{dataListView.processaResposta(l)}" event="click"
                    update="formulario"></p:ajax>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certo" itemValue="Certo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Errado" itemValue="Errado" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>

            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{dataListView.resposta[l]}"
                rendered="#{dataListView.resposta[l] != null}">
                <p:ajax event="click" update="formulario"></p:ajax>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certo" itemValue="Certo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Errado" itemValue="Errado" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:dataList>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And in bean...

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DataListView implements Serializable {

    private List<String> lista;
    private Map<String, String> resposta;
    private String teste;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("1");
        lista.add("2");
        lista.add("3");
        lista.add("4");
        lista.add("5");
        resposta = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public List<String> getLista() {
        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<String> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getResposta() {
        return resposta;
    }

    public void setResposta(Map<String, String> resposta) {
        this.resposta = resposta;
    }

    public void processaResposta(String action) {
        resposta.put(action, teste);
        teste = null;
    }

    public String getTeste() {
        return teste;
    }

    public void setTeste(String teste) {
        this.teste = teste;
    }

}
```

After put a answer and ID, you need to make the value 'teste' null.